# Why are some outlets still out after replacing an outlet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

So I had an outlet that was sparking and sometimes cutting out (till I moved it to an angle) so I decided to change it. Turned the breaker off, replaced it, turned it back on and find out my room and a few other things on my side of the house don't have power. Now this had happened before with my bathroom on the same circuit so I know what breaker it is. So a few outlets on the way from the breaker box (on the same breaker as my room) to my room work, and stop about halfway through. I bought a multimeter and tested my outlet and get ~120 Volts. Tested a light switch (that wasn't working but on the same breaker) and same thing, so I'm at a loss of what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On the old receptacle, are any tabs broken off? Was the old receptacle anything special like a GFCI?  Are you jabbing wires into the backside holes, or wrapping wires around the screws?

Comment: @Harper It's a normal outlet, doesn't look like anything is broken off but here's pictures of the old one for reference. http://imgur.com/a/3Uw27k5

Comment: Jim it's in the pictures (4) but they're so perfectly side-on that I can't quite tell.  I don't see any tabs at all, usually the neutral tab is intact. I can't quite see.   Got an ohmmeter?  Can you measure continuity/resistance between the two brass/hot screws and the two silver/neutral screws?

Comment: @JimStewart is it the piece of metal connecting the screws on each side? If so they're both there.

Comment: Strange in the bottom view I see what looks like tabs in place, but from the sides I cannot tell, but given your statement we let's say that the tabs are intact. This means that its not a certain kind of circuit called a multiwire branch circuit. It means that a single hot will power both receptacles and it means that if you have two blacks, one on each screw, that one of the blacks is the incoming hot and the other is the outgoing hot to other receptacles. Same with the neutral side.

Comment: You can test a point, get 120 V, and have the circuit *not* work. That can happen if the neutral path is broken, either a loose connection or disconnection. Get one of those plug-on receptacle testers. It will indicate multiple faults, including open neutral. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Power-Gear-3-Wire-Receptacle-Tester-50542/206212329?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD27E%7C27-11_TOOLS_%26_ACCESSORIES%7CNA%7CPLA%7c71700000034238984%7c58700003943782712%7c92700031954542185&gclid=

Comment: You have a volt meter--does it have a resistance setting which might be designated Ohms scale? If so, put it there and measure the resistance between the two screws on the same side. Low or zero means the tabs are in place. Warning: do not use the resistance function with a powered circuit; you can damage the meter doing this.

Comment: @JimStewart yeah the old outlet is fine, I got the plug in receptor checker and it said I had some of the wiring wrong, so I fixed it and still didn't work. Plugged it into two of my other outlets in my room and it says the hot and ground are reversed but they worked before so I don't know if that means anything. Another outlet outside my room (that's dead ATM) just has the left (red) light on, oddly just that light being on isn't on the product as an option so I don't know what it means. I bought this one. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Tools-Outlet-Tester-Green-MS112H/206029

Comment: So actually the originally replaced outlet works again due to me fixing it to be "correct" according to the checker, I'm going to do the same thing for another dead outlet and see what happens

Comment: Did the same thing with another outlet in my room (this involved swapping the hot and ground, then swapping the hot and neutral) and it has power again, I'd do this for all my outlets but I have some lights on this breaker and I don't know if that would fix them, I'm not sure where to go from here so any guidance would be great

Comment: Those "magic-8-ball" 3-lamp testers often give you very strange answers that are not true - hence the nickname.  What they *are* good for, is removing an unrelated phenomenon called "phantom voltage", which can cause a lot of problems for DVMs.   Stick a 3-lamp tester in one socket and measure the other with a DVM, you will get true readings.

Comment: "hot-ground reverse" is the magic 8-ball answer most likely to be totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is first systematically correct all the receptacles in one circuit, then examine the switches for the light fixtures and insure that the switches are in the hot line and not in the neutral. This means that each 1-pole switch should have an always hot on one contact and switched hot on the other. Note that a white colored wire can be and often is used as a hot or switched hot in a loop for a light.

I hope this won't happen but it *could* be that if you correct a receptacle and turn the breaker on, it will trip because incorrect wiring in either a remaining receptacle or in a loop for a light makes a short. If that happens you will have to correct all the remaining wiring before proceeding, instead of going receptacle by receptacle, switch by switch, light by light.

Finally, after all the receptacles and switches have been corrected move up to the light fixtures and insure that the switched hot goes to the proper wire lead or contact. In a screw base fixture this means the central contact is switched hot and the neutral. In others generally the switched hot lead will be black. Note that a white wire could be used for a switched hot so you could be connecting a white wire to a black wire (something you would usually not do with receptacles).

Comment: I was about to write something similar. The only thing I'd add is **As you work through the connections, if any are backstabs, move those wires to the screw connections.**